# Magento2: How to create upload multiple images attribute to category programmatically in admin

Tags: magento2

I need to create upload multiple images attribute to category programmatically in admin.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Comment: No @ManishMaheshwari